# Calculate logarithm of factorial

Tags: performance

Here are three methods to calculate logarithm of factorial N: lgN!
The first method uses recursion and store each recursive value in an array
The second method uses recursive without array
The third method uses FOR loop.

After some testing, the third method has best performance, then the second one, the first one has bad performance.

My question is why first method is worse than second one
and though the third method has best performance, its value is different to the others,there is anything wrong in it?

```
/**
 * method 1 
 * calculate lgN! with recursion and keep every recursive value
     * in an array. It has bad performance, once n reached about 6000, it 
     * will throw stackoverflow exception
 * @param a
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
private static double lgNFact1(double[] a ,int n){
    if(n==1)
        a[n-1]=0;
    else
        a[n-1]=Math.log(n) + lgNFact1(a,n-1);
    return a[n-1];
}

/**
 * Method 2 have a little better performance, in my case n can reach 10000!,than throws stackoverflow exception
 * @param n
 * @return
 */
private static double lgNFact2(int n) {
    if(n==1)
        return 0;
    return Math.log(n)+lgNFact2(n-1);
}
/**
     * Method 3, based on logarithm formula, we can use for loop to get lgN!
 * log5!=log5+log4+log3+log2+log1

 * @param n
 * @return
 */
private static double lgNFact3(int n) {
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        sum+=Math.log(n);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Below is test, when n equals 10, we can see the third one is different to above two cases

case1 n=10, result:15.104412573075518

case2 n= 10, result:15.104412573075518

case3 n=10, result:23.025850929940464

Comment: In your third method you are taking the log of n instead of i.

Comment: updated method 3 based on kezi' comments, now all the results are same. so please ignore my second questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the recursive solutions, each call to the function sets up memory locations for that function, hooks up metadata about the caller, etc. before it gets on with the calculation. The for loop simply calculates the value and is done. The first method has to handle copying an array in addition to a number, so it takes a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Summed up: Method #1 is copying an array on the stack which takes time and memory and is why it caps out at 6000. Method 2 is recursive and thus is also capped out by how big the stack can grow. It has to spend time allocating memory for each recursive call. Method #3 doesn’t use recursive calls so doesn’t have to bloat the stack and doesn’t have to spend time pushing stack frames.

Answer (score 0):

Which of method 3 or a tail call variant of method 2 will be most efficient depends on the language. As it stands, method 2 does not use tail call recursion. A simple change to make it use tail call:

```
/**
 * Tail call method 2 may or may not throw a stackoverflow exception, depending
 * on whether the language supports tail call optimization.
 */
private static double tailLgNFact2 (int n, double sum=0.0)
{
    if (n <= 1) return sum;
    return tailLgNFact2(n-1, Math.log(n)+sum);
}
```

Based on other questions at stack overflow, Java compilers apparently do not support tail call optimization, but some Java runtimes apparently do. With functional programming languages that do support tail call optimization, the tail call version may have better performance than the looped version.